# Getting 400 Bad Request Running 'react-script start'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axios, httpclient, react-scripts

I'm developing a simple RoR backend, React frontend application, and I'm having a few API requests to fetch data from the database. Currently, I'm using axios to make the request like below:

```
axios.get('/api/session/user')
```

The problem is when I run the server using `bundle exec rails server` on my terminal, it makes the right requests and fetch data. However, when I run `npm start` which runs 'react-script start', I'm always getting 400 Bad Request on any api that I make a request.

I tested with the Postman to get or post data both running `rails server` and `npm start` but I'm getting 400 Bad requests only when I'm using `npm start`. What do I need to do in order to make it run in `react-script start` (`npm start`)?

In package.json, I have the proxy set up as `"proxy": "http://localhost:3000/"`. However when I change the port to 3001, I get 500 Internal Server Error instead of 400 Bad Request. Both port 3000 and 3001 work fine when I run `rails server`.

Comment: Are your rails and react projects are in different directories? Or are you using `react-rails` gem or webpacker in Rails app to use react as front-end?

Comment: I'm using webpack. In the main Rails directory, I have the frontend folder with the entry file specificed in ```webpack.config```, and I have the client folder that has a separate ```package.json``` file that has the script ```react-script start```. Inside the client foler, I have the public folder that has the ```index.html```, and the src folder with all the react and redux stuffs....

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand about your file structure. Can you edit your question to include `tree` like file structure? Also, Are you using standalone `webpack` or do you have `gem webpacker` in your rails `Gemfile`?

Comment: https://github.com/hcheon549/BluePlate

Comment: The above link is not working. I think it's a private repo or link is invalid.

Comment: Just made it public. Try it now?

Comment: In your `frontend/blueplate.jsx`, you have `import configureStore from "./store/store";` - But there is no such file in your `frontend` folder. I think your referencing them in a different way. All your code react resides in `client` folder, so I think the problem is in referencing.